# How do you compare keys & values in a JSON objects when one object has extra keys using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, compare, lodash

I have two JSON objects like so:

```
var obj1 = {a: "apple", b: "banana", c: "carrot"}
var obj2 = {a: "apple", e: “egg” b: "banana", c: "carrot", d: "dog"}
```

I want to be able to have a Boolean check comparing the two objects without having to remove data from either one. For example, if I were to use the data above, the Boolean check should return ***true*** because the values of the keys that are in both objects match.

However, lets say `obj1` stays the same but `obj2` is the following:

```
var obj1 = {a: "apple", b: "banana", c: "carrot"}
var obj2 = {a: "ant", e: “egg” b: "banana", c: "carrot", d: "dog"}
```

With this data, it should return **false** because the ***a*** key's value is not matching even though other fields are matching and some fields are not present in both objects.

Any ideas? I would prefer to use Lodash since they have a quality library. Originally was trying to use `_.isEqual(obj1, obj2)` but it doesn't work for my exact needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.isMatch` can be of help. Check the below snippet

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot"
}
var obj2 = {
  a: "apple",
  e: "egg",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot",
  d: "dog"
}

console.log(_.isMatch(obj2, obj1));

var obj1 = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot"
}
var obj2 = {
  a: "ant",
  e: "egg",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot",
  d: "dog"
}

console.log(_.isMatch(obj2, obj1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** that `_.isMatch(obj1, obj2)` will not work. You will need to put some logic to determine which object has more keys and pass it as first argument.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Still learning Lodash so this really helps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if `lodash` has such a method. But you can achieve the same result by just utilizing `Object.etnries` and `Array.every` methods.

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot"
}
var obj2 = {
  a: "apple",
  b: "banana",
  c: "carrot",
  d: "dog",
  e: "egg"
}


var obj3 = {a: "apple", b: "banana", c: "carrot"}
var obj4 = {a: "ant", e: "egg" ,b: "banana", c: "carrot", d: "dog"}

function checkEquality(a, b) {
  const entries1 = Object.entries(a);
  const entries2 = Object.entries(b);

  const short = entries1.length > entries2 ? entries2 : entries1; // pick the shorter array
  const long = short === entries1 ? b : a;

  const isEqual = short.every(([k, v]) => long[k] === v);
  return isEqual;

}



console.log(checkEquality(obj1, obj2))
console.log(checkEquality(obj3, obj4))
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't use Lodash this is still a quality answer to help me expand my JS skills, thanks a bunch!